# Glassfish debug from command line

Tags: glassfish-3

I'm running Glassfish on a remote machine.  Is there a command to start GF in debug mode from the command prompt?  The remote machine runs Ubuntu 10.04, my machine runs Windows 7 (not sure if this is important).

I connect without a problem and know the commands to start and stop the server remotely.  I even found [this documentation](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4495/gcode?l=en&a=view). Unfortunately, I think the answer to my question is "no", but I wanted to put it to the SO community before giving up hope.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The start-domain command has a debug option:

```
asadmin start-domain --debug=true
```

Comment: You will have to telnet/ssh/whatever to the server to do this.  start-domain is a 'local' asadmin subcommand.

Comment: That does the trick as far as the command line goes, now I just need to get my project to run in debug mode from NetBeans. I'm getting a "Connection timed out" error causing the build to fail.

Comment: For particular domain add 'your-domain-name' to the end. So it will look like: asadmin start-domain --debug=true your-domain-name